# Anyone know of an Asp.Net C# CMS type system with a Forms Module

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, content-management

We have a large internal data collection website. I don't have time to create form based data collection pages for every department. I was thinking that there might be some kind of WYSIWYG forms creation module that could be run on top of our website. System would be like a cms, but one that allows custom pages to be created. All the form page setup is run from the database. So when a department head needs to implement a forms data collection page they can go in and create a page, and drag and drop all the form fields and position the elements. Then all form submission data is saved to one primary set of tables that I can query and generate custom reports on the data or utilize for custom page processing.

System should allow:
Choose the names of fields on the form
Choose the field type:  textbox, checkbox, radio buttons, dropdown
Choose the validation: required, max length, data type, as well as the error message shown when validation fails
Choose the order in which the fields are displayed
To be able to add conditional logic to the fields (i.e. if this is yes, then that is required or hide that field)
Choose to capture data into a database when the form is submitted
To retrieve the data stored in the database so it can be transformed into something meaningful
To be able to create forms by copying other forms and editing them
To be able to reuse the forms in many pages
To be able to add pagination to the forms (so the form isn't soooo long)
To be able to display a customized message when the form is submitted.

Comment: Supposedely Sitefinity will have a forms module in version 4.
http://www.sitefinity.com/support/forums/sitefinity-3-x/developing-with-sitefinity/forms-module.aspx but I think it might be to far out from a timeframe perspective

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the BizForms functionality in [Kentico](http://www.kentico.com).  I have used Kentico for a bit, just getting into the forms part, but seems like it will meet most, maybe even all of your requirements.

Comment: I checked out their features and you might be right. I will have to try it out and see if it will work out. How do you like the backend part, is it easy to navigate their table structure and figure out what part of the forms belong to what. I would be writing custom pages that parse out the collected form data?

Comment: I don't have much time to evaluate the program yet I need to make a recommendation, know what I mean?

Answer (score 3):

[Kentico CMS](http://kenticocms.com/free-cms-asp-net.aspx) might be what you're looking for. Alternatively, you might want to look into [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/).

Comment: I am dead set against DNN, but i will take a look at Kentico

Answer (score 1):

[N2](http://n2cms.com/) - an open source ASP.NET CMS, has nice design for customization, a lot of modules, and it has integration with yet another forum project.

Comment: I had looked at the feature set, but I didn't see anything related to a Forms type module or system. Does it have one and I just missed that.

Answer (score 1):

http://umbraco.org/ - is another good CMS to take a look at

Comment: I looked at Umbraco 4 a few months back , I don't recollect there being anything like what I described. Is there some kind of add on package, nitro or whatever they call it?

Comment: Looks like you are looking for something called Umbraco Forms - http://umbraco.org/products/umbraco-forms according to their web site it's going to be released this year. 

Anyway as far as I've investigated umbraco you can create the functionality you need using XSLT templates.

Comment: You must be a genious, because I couldn't find that on their website, there is no link, and I even googled "umbraco forms" before I posted that last comment. Anyway, it isn't out yet and I have no idea how to create the functionality using xslt templates. I want something already built and simpe to use